# Recursively-placed components not displaying

Tags: angular

I have the following component, which displays child components of its own type for each element in an array.

```
@Component({
  selector:'pane',
  template: `
       <pane [item]="item">
           <div> 
               <pane *ngFor="#subItem of item.subItems" [item]="subItem"></pane>
           </div>
           <div innerHtml="item.getContent()"></div>
       </pane>
   `
)}   
export class Pane {
  @Input() item: any;
}
```

But the `pane` components inside the `ngFor` are not being displayed as expected - I see the correct number of `pane` elements, but they are not populated with the template contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you need to declare the component's own type in the `directives` property of the decorator, as you do with any other directive.

Adding:

```
directives: [Pane]
```

to your component metadata
results in the expected behavior.